# Using Display Ports with Intel 4600 Graphics

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have run into this problem with a Dell 9020 running Windows 7 and a Dell 7020 running Windows 10: but web searches indicate that the problem may be with the built-in Intel 4600 Graphics, as this is what my two systems have in common, and which people with other manufacturer's PCs have also encountered.  The problem is that the Display Ports are apparently available to some users: but I and many other people can't get the Display ports to show up.

Both of my systems are completely up-to-date with all of Dell's supplied updates, including the BIOS, and with their graphics driver (which is supplied by Intel). I've used their update scanner / downloader / installer which says everything is up-to-date, and it hasn't helped.

One suggestion came from Dell, saying that "multiple devices" has to be enabled in the BIOS.  The BIOS on these two systems don't have that setting.

Suggestions have been made that the monitor (or, in my case, a TV working through a Display Port to HDMI adapter) must be powered on when the system boots.  I've tried it with the device active during boot and with it not active and only plugged in after boot, but neither works.  The two Display Ports never show up in Device Manager, or in the Intel Control Panel, or in the Windows Display control panel.  I think they should be there even if there is nothing plugged in.

I am using a short Display Port to HDMI cable / adapter.  I tested this on a different system with a Radion Graphics card to a TV and it work, so I'm confident that it's not the cable.

As I mentioned, many people have reported the problem, but nobody in the Dell conference, or the Intel conference, or other sites I've found with web searches seems to have a solution.  I'm hoping people here are more knowledgeable and have a solution, or at least some better suggestions on what to try.

Comment: `so I'm confident that it's not the cable` Is the TV the only display you have tested? Do you have any display that has a DP-in? One possibility I can think of is, the DP on your Radeon card is actually a DP++, in which case you can use a passive DP->HDMI adapter, whereas the DP on your Dells' motherboard is "pure" DP, in which case you need an active DP->HDMI adapter.

Comment: I'm also not seeing in Device Manager under Display adapters my DisplayPort. They are connected to the display card, not directly to the PC bus, so have no business showing up in there.

Comment: On retrospection, I agree that they're not going to show up in Device Manager.  There actual.y is no "card", the graphics are built into the CPU or the support chips, but your reasoning is correct.  The comment about the TV is also close: I have researched a variety of Display Port to HDMI adapters, and all of the ones that have descriptions say they only work in one direction. I thought I said that all tests were done with a Display Port to HDMI adapter going to a TV.

Comment: Nevertheless, I did try a second, older TV, and something about it make the Display Port "Happy".  I will have to investigate more to find out why one TV worked and the other didn't.  Using Display Port has it's own problems, as Intel always thinks the Display Port should come before an SVGA output and it makes it harder to boot unless the BIOS lets you select the output.  I will investigate more, but looks like there is something about some TV connections that the Display Port doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question, I can verify that you can connect 3 1920x1200 24" monitors to a Dell 9020 with the Integrated Intel HD Graphics 4600 video using a single DP cable to the first monitor and another DP cable daisy chained from the first to the second and another DP cable daisy chained from the second to the third. I'm currently typing this answer using the described system. The monitors are Dell U2415's with DP1.2 enabled. The video card driver version is 20.19.15.5063 dated 10/29/2018. Processor is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790 CPU @ 3.60GHz with 32GB. The OS is Windows 10 Pro 22H2 OS build 19045.3803. Let me know if there's any other info you need. I don't know the BIOS version right now but I do remember seeing a multi-monitor check box on one of the BIOS screens.